# Native Client(NaCl) support with Edge extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient, microsoft-edge-extension, nacl-cryptography

I am developing an edge extension, where I need to use Nacl to encrypt my request while sending to backend application using native messaging. How can I use Nacl with edge extension background.js.

Edge extension's Backgound.js does not work with Nacl.
Chrome extension's background.js works with the same NaCl files.

Comment: NaCL is implemented only in Chrome. It can't be supported in any other browser because it's too deeply integrated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any alternative for NaCl in Edge?

Comment: Perhaps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly

Comment: NACL is way faster than WASM even in 2022